# accessing array by key returns null, while dumping looks good

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, parsed from a yaml string, which behaves weird. This code produces the following output:

```
var_dump($params['layout']);

var_dump($params);

foreach($params as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ': ' . $value . '<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
NULL

array(4) {
  ["layout"]=>
  string(4) "home"
  ["title"]=>
  string(4) "home"
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-03-21"
  ["description"]=>
  string(55) "Everything is alive and other tales from the thresholds"
}

layout: home
title: home
date: 2017-03-21
description: Everything is alive and other tales from the thresholds
```

Why does accessing the first item by key return null?

Comment: try var_dump($params["layout"]); once

Comment: In your array "layout" is really `"&#65279;layout"` It's  ByteOrderMark https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: you need to remove space in `layout` key

Comment: Thank you splash58, didn't think of that.